# in-app purchases available on one device but not another

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm implementing in-app purchases in my app, but I hit a problem. When I request for my products on a tablet it works but when I'm requesting my products on another it doesn't.

Here is the context in which I'm testing:

Device on which the in-app purchases work: iPad 2, iOS 7.
Device on which the in-app purchases doesn't work: iPad 3, iOS 6.

I am not signed-in on neither in the app store.

I've restarted the OS, I've deleted the app and re-installed it but it still doesn't work on the iPad 3. What could be the problem?

**UPDATE 1**

the error i'm getting for the device on which i have problems requesting is "invalid product identificer"

**UPDATE 2**

i've also tested on an iPad 3(iOS7) and iPad mini (iOS6) and it works.

Comment: what kind of error do you get?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha invalid product identifier

Comment: are you're logged out of your iTunes account on the device where you get the error?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha as i've said, i am not signed-in on neither in the app store, so yes.

Comment: your iPad 3(iOS6) is jailbreak ?

Comment: @Rushabh yes it is! i didn't know it was, this is the problem. Please provide it as an answer.

Comment: @BadescuAlexandru if my answer help to you so accept it. its useful for someone else :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you tried everything but still get invalid product id, in case your device is jailbroken, try factory restore. I tried everything and didn't get it to work til i restored to factory version. Somehow jailbroken device is not able to test out in app purchase